Haversine Loss function: No gradients provided for any variable?
I'm trying to implement a custom loss function, the haversine loss that computes the distance between two points on a sphere. The coordinates of the classes are saved in a csv, hence I have to convert the true and predicted index into the class names ('cluster') to extract the corresponding coordinates from the csv. (The csv only contains the cluster (integer) and the coordinate pair, Center_Longitude and Center_Latitude as float32) I think the extraction of the coordinates, as well as the haversine computation work (see the output below). But in the end I don't know why I get this error: ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable.
My output is a softmax layer, hence I am using argmax to get the prediction with the highest probability. I am thinking, this might cause the problems, but I am still unsure on how to solve it. Why do I get no gradients? How could I alter my code to get it to work properly?
def haversine_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    pred_index = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
    true_index = tf.cast(y_true, tf.int32)


    tf.print("Predicted indices:", pred_index)
    tf.print("True indices:", true_index)

   
    pred_class_names = tf.gather(class_names, pred_index)
    true_class_names = tf.gather(class_names, true_index)

    
    tf.print("Predicted class names:", pred_class_names)
    tf.print("True class names:", true_class_names)


    pred_lat_lon = tf.stack([
        tf.gather(clusters_df['Center_Latitude'].values, pred_index),
        tf.gather(clusters_df['Center_Longitude'].values, pred_index)
    ], axis=-1)

    true_lat_lon = tf.stack([
        tf.gather(clusters_df['Center_Latitude'].values, true_index),
        tf.gather(clusters_df['Center_Longitude'].values, true_index)
    ], axis=-1)

  
    tf.print("Predicted lat/lon:", pred_lat_lon)
    tf.print("True lat/lon:", true_lat_lon)

 
    lat1, lon1 = pred_lat_lon[:, 0], pred_lat_lon[:, 1]
    lat2, lon2 = true_lat_lon[:, 0], true_lat_lon[:, 1]

  
    distance = haversine_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)

    tf.print("Calculated distances:", distance)

    return tf.reduce_mean(distance)

def haversine_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):

    lat1 = tf.cast(lat1, tf.float32) * (tf.constant(m.pi, dtype=tf.float32) / 180.0)
    lon1 = tf.cast(lon1, tf.float32) * (tf.constant(m.pi, dtype=tf.float32) / 180.0)
    lat2 = tf.cast(lat2, tf.float32) * (tf.constant(m.pi, dtype=tf.float32) / 180.0)
    lon2 = tf.cast(lon2, tf.float32) * (tf.constant(m.pi, dtype=tf.float32) / 180.0)

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = tf.sin(dlat / 2)**2 + tf.cos(lat1) * tf.cos(lat2) * tf.sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * tf.asin(tf.sqrt(a))

    R = 6371.0
    return R * c

Epoch 1/25
Predicted indices: [1124]
True indices: [604]
Predicted class names: ["8983"]
True class names: ["8463"]
Predicted lat/lon: [[51.227374672500062 7.2118920326250366]]
True lat/lon: [[49.075162783850026 9.48693443665003]]
Calculated distances: [289.012787]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypath.py", line 171, in <module>
    model.fit(
  File "mypath.py\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py"", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "mypath.py\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\optimizers\base_optimizer.py", line 662, in _filter_empty_gradients
    raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable.")
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable.

Process finished with exit code 1


argmax is not differentiable, that is why you get no gradients.

Do you have any suggestions how I could solve this problem?
How could I calculate the distance, if I can't get the prediction with the highest probability?

You could just have your model output the coordinates directly (turning it into a regression problem).
